# ??? Attempted to access cmtx(1.00024,1); index must be a positive integer or logical

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

I am working with a image . and i am applying entropic thresholding on the image,and i get the error. how to solve this error?

```
??? Attempted to access cmtx(1.00024,1); index must be a positive integer or logical."    
  Error in ==> file1>GABOR_Callback at 809

     cmtx(fix(rt(m,n))+1,fix(rt(m,n+1))+1) = cmtx(rt(m,n)+1,rt(m+1,n+1)+1) + 1
```

I tried to solve this error using fix and round function. but it dint work for me.can somebody please help me. here rt is a image which is the output of my convoluted image. So i cant change the values of rt image matrix. My code for entropic thresholding is.

```
     [M,N] =size(rt);     
     cmtx = zeros(256,256);     
     for m = 1:M-1
          for n = 1:N-1        
       cmtx(rt(m,n)+1,rt(m,n+1)+1) = cmtx(rt(m,n)+1,rt(m+1,n+1)+1) + 1;
        end
     end
   scmtx = sum(cmtx(:)); prob = cmtx/scmtx;     
   emax = -100; for i=1:255 

   probA = 0;   
    probC = 0;

   subProbA = prob(1:i,1:i);
   probA = sum(subProbA(:));

  HA(i) = -0.5*(probA*log2(probA+0.0000001));
  subProbC = prob(i+1:256,i+1:256);

   probC = sum(subProbC(:));
   HC(i) = -0.5*(probC*log2(probC+0.0000001));

    e1(i) = HA(i) + HC(i); 
    if e1(i) >= emax
           emax = e1(i);
    tt1 = i;
    end
end
```

end

here rt is my image
[image]

Comment: In your first code snippet, you are only using fix for the assignment indices.  Have you tried using fix on this source indices as well?  You could try rtf = fix(rt) and then just use rtf in place of rt.

Comment: thank you sir,dat idea din strike me at all. and sir after i run this i get a small dot as my output...is there any mistake in my entropic code.

Answer (score 1):

Pixels are discrete and therefore must be indexed using integers. You cannot index an array with anything other than integer values. In this case if you index an element of rt or cmtx, you are accessing the pixel value. When you call...

```
cmtx(rt(m,n) + 1, rt(m+1,n+1) + 1) + 1
```

The value of rt(m,n) will most likely not be an integer. It really makes no sense to me why you would want to index cmtx with a pixel **value** contained in rt. Can you explain or give a source for entropic thresholding?

Also, can you please explain the motivation for this code:

```
for m = 1:M-1
   for n = 1:N-1        
       cmtx(rt(m,n)+1,rt(m,n+1)+1) = cmtx(rt(m,n)+1,rt(m+1,n+1)+1) + 1;
   end
end
```

Are you trying to add a specific value to all elements of rt to produce cmtx? What is the desired relationship between rt and cmtx?

If cmtx is simply a copy of rt with the addition of a value to each pixel of rt then a for loop is not necessary. This would suffice.

```
cmtx = rt + myValue;
```